# Compiling SCSS Files

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am into UI development since long tears back, but I haven't required to work in Sass. But I am going to develop a new project where I have to work in Sass. Basically I am new in Sass but after going through the Guide I think I can manage it.

**About compilation**. I am familiar with Gulp, so I can do it. But I was wondering , since I am new in it about any tools which can compile also and I came accross [Prepos](https://prepros.io/) and found it's good to start. I prefer the desktop notifications on SCSS writing errors in Prepos which I initially require as I am new in Sass which in Gulp I do not find any desktop notification.

My question is did anyone worked with prepos? Shall I go with Prepos or stay in Gulp.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepos can be a good option, But it can become a nightmare. I recommend to start being familiar with nodejs and the terminal interface.

Reason: There is more tools to manage via terminal and it can be tricky and the beginning but it's quicker and you will be able to have more information about the process.

Cheers

Comment: Yes I was also thinking that. Actually I got confused whether I use propose or go for node.  Thanks for your prompt reply.. I got my answer.

Comment: Agree with @Nestor, get familiar with working with the terminal and node. FYI you can add Gulp Notify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify) to your Gulpfile when processing the Sass and it will give you notifications of errors and updates.

Comment: @AlxTheRed Thanks for your help